# How to create user notification message similar to JGrowl

Tags: javafx-2, javafx, javafx-8

I started to work to user notification message similar to JGrowl for JavaFX.

```
public void newMessage()
{

    final Stage newConnDialog = new Stage();
    newConnDialog.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
    newConnDialog.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);

    // Set pisition
    newConnDialog.setX(1050); //secondStage.setX(primaryStage.getX() + 250);
    newConnDialog.setY(150);

    GridPane grid = new GridPane();
    grid.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    grid.setHgap(5);
    grid.setVgap(5);
    grid.setPadding(new Insets(20, 20, 20, 20));

    // text
    Text productName = new Text("Test");
    productName.setFont(Font.font("Verdana", 12));
    grid.add(productName, 0, 2);

    // Configure dialog size and background color
    Scene aboutDialogScene = new Scene(grid, 200, 100, Color.WHITESMOKE);
    newConnDialog.setScene(aboutDialogScene);
    newConnDialog.show();
}
```

I have a basic knowledge about JavaFX. Can you give me some basic advice what will be the best way to implement this component. For example do I need to create new Stage or I can use other component as stage. How I can hide the component after 10 seconds activity and etc. Any advice will be highly appreciated.

P.S.
I found [this](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/bluepapa32/20091020/1256058875) example for JavaFX 1.3 Maybe it can be rewritten for JavaFX 2.2?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is one possible solution by using the [Enzo  library](https://bitbucket.org/hansolo/enzo/wiki/Home):

> ```
> // Create a custom Notification without icon  Notification info = new
> Notification("Title", "Info-Message");
>
> // Show the custom notification   
> Notifier.INSTANCE.notify(info);
>
> // Show a predefined Warning notification
> Notifier.INSTANCE.notifyWarning("This is a warning");
> ```
>
> [image]

[Source](https://harmoniccode.blogspot.com/2013/07/need-some-notification.html#comment-form)

Comment: the lib behind that is unavailable.

Comment: The link in the blog post is broken, but you can still access the author's source on github: [link](https://github.com/HanSolo/Enzo)

Comment: Did you use a library or you  `Notification` class from `javax.management` package ?

Comment: Again please, I don't understand the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ControlsFx library to create notifications
http://docs.controlsfx.org/org/controlsfx/control/NotificationPane.html

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

you can try JFXToast see [github](https://github.com/Abojemy/JFXToast/blob/master/Toasts.java)
that can help you doing this work

this is an class for empelement toast in javafx

Comment: links are highly discourage you should provide some details about link.

Comment: Link is dead.  This one may be comparable: https://github.com/vincenzopalazzo/JFXToast